# Use React router and CSSTransitionGroup caused errors

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was trying to add some css animation into my project, then I got these errors.

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Route`.
    in Route (created by Routes)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by Routes)
    in Routes

Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Route`.
```

This is my code

```
import "../css/main.scss";
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route,BrowserRouter,Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Body from './home';
import Detail from './detail';
import Form from './form';
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';

class Routes extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route render={( { location } )=>(
        <div id="display">

          <CSSTransitionGroup transitionName="fade" transitionEnterTimeout={400} transitionLeaveTimeout={250} >

        <Route exact path="/voteapp/" component={Body} location={location} key={location.key} />
        <Route exact path="/voteapp/addvote/" component={Form} location={location} key={location.key} />
        <Route path="/voteapp/display/:pk" component={Detail} location={location} key={location.key} />

      </CSSTransitionGroup>

        </div>
      )} />
    </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Routes />,document.getElementById("content"));
```

Related package information:

```
"react-router": "^4.1.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
"react-transition-group": "^2.1.0"
```

When I commented the CSSTransitionGroup tag in the code, other things worked fine.Is there a problem at the way I import the module?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
```

is not supported anymore and you should (install if needed) and import `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`

```
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react/lib/ReactCSSTransitionGroup'
```

and than it will work.

And BTW I think you should put `<Switch>` between transition-tag and routes so the location and key params you will handle only on the Switch. Or there is my combination of Transition and Switch I am using: https://github.com/melounek/switch-css-transition-group